# XNA 2D - How can I draw a sprite over another?

Tags: xna-4.0

I'm working on a simple 2D game that is similar to the classic Invader arcade. What I want to know is:

How can I draw a new sprite over the player sprite upon colliding with an enemy/a bullet?
Better yet, how can I hide the player so that the hit animation can be shown?

I got the collision detection up and running except for the hit animation. It's being drawn behind the player current position which is awkward.

Comment: Maybe give us your draw code, then it would be easier to help.

Comment: Never mind everyone. I just got it. All I have to do is change from spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront,BlendState.AlphaBlend) to spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate,BlendState.AlphaBlend)

Comment: Try not to use Immediate, but rather use Defered. If it will work, it will be better.

Comment: "If it will work, it will be better." Incredibly overgeneralized statement that's not true for many scenes that use multiple render states.

Answer (score 5):

Please investigate the parameters of the [spriteBatch.Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx)-method. Try not to feel intimidated by the sheer number of parameters of the largest one. The [last parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx) there is the "layerDepth" which should be a floating point value between 0 and 1. This parameter will be used (only) if you begin your drawing with [SpriteSortMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx).BackToFront or FrontToBack.
If you make use of the layerDepth you don't have to worry to make the Draw()-calls in any particular order.

Comment: Is that the best approach? I tend to add a `Z` field and sort sprites by Z before rendering.